# Book with three young characters on an adventure: female with a rhino horn on her head, male with scales, and female's cousin

Tags: story-identification, books

I **loved** this book but cannot remember the title or even any names from within the book itself.

I read it a couple of years back. It was a physical book with a plain black cover. I believe the title had "Beast" in it unless my brain is just telling me that because the story consisted of beasts.

There were 3 main characters, a male, female, and the female's younger male cousin. In the story this boy (a peasant?) was once friends with a young, royal girl (who preferred to be more tomboy than girly) but they were separated since it was forbidden. Though, they did not care.

I remember this one part where apparently they were in some sort of warehouse and had to sneak something out of it. And they found out about some tree?  They befriended goblins to be able to go down through their tunnels underground so they could get to this tree.

They made their way to the tree and began fighting it and some other people there. One of them touched the tree and everything went black for the 3 main characters and then they woke up, each in a separate cell.

The female had a large rhino horn on her head, the male had scales (he thought he was a merman but turned out to be a dragon), and I do not remember what the female's cousin had.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Check out the [other suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for story-id questions to see if they help you remember any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: There's certainly no shortage of [books with "Beast" or "beasts" in the title](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=beast&type=Fiction+Titles)